# How to hold the star rating even after updating the page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a 5 star rating system plugin using jQuery in wordpress (backend). The star values are also getting updated in to post meta table. If I have give a post 3 star and updates the page, the value gets stored in post meta but after updating the page the ratings wont be displaying. So my question is how to hold those values even after updating the page until we manually edit the star ratings.

```
<?php

/* Plugin Name: Star Rating
 * Version: 1.0
 */

class starrating{

    public function __construct(){
    add_action('add_meta_boxes',array($this,'my_meta'));
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this ,'starscript' ));
    add_action('save_post', array($this,'save_field'));
    }


    public function my_meta()

    {

        add_meta_box(
       'my_custom_meta',
       'Created By',
        array($this,'my_meta_box_mes'),
       'a_z',
       'side',
       'low'
    );

    }

    public function save_field($post_id)

    {
    update_post_meta($post_id,'starrating',$_POST['rating']);    
 }


    public function my_meta_box_mes()
    {

    ?>
     <label>Please Rate Your Ratings !!</label>
     <p>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
<ul class="rating" onMouseOut="resetRating();">
  <li name="star" value="one" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="two" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="three" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="four" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="five" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
</ul>
    </p>



     <?php
    }
    public function starscript(){
     wp_enqueue_script( 'star_id',content_url() . '/plugins/star_rating/js/starrating.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery_id', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'styl_id',content_url() . '/plugins/star_rating/css/star.css' ); 

    }
}
$star=new starrating();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in "my_meta_box_mes" method if post meta already exist.
If exist change the html code.

I write code for you but it's just for example.
It's will work but this is a bad practice to do it:

```
public function my_meta_box_mes(){
?>
     <label>Please Rate Your Ratings !!</label>
     <p>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
<ul class="rating" onMouseOut="resetRating();">
  <li name="star" value="one" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="two" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="three" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="four" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="five" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
</ul>
    </p>
<?php

    // Get current rating value
    $currentRating = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'starrating', true );
    if( $currentRating ){
        // trigger click event with js on the current star value
        ?>
        <script>
            document.querySelector( "ul.rating li[value='<?php echo $currentRating; ?>']" ).click();
        </script>

        <?php
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks  A Lot ! i too worked out a solution which is working just fine. but appreciate the help brother

Answer (score 0):

```
public function my_meta_box_mes()
    {
        $star=(int)get_post_meta($_GET['post'],'starrating',true);
        //var_dump($star);exit();

    ?>
     <label>Please Rate Your Ratings !!</label>
     <p>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
<ul class="rating" onMouseOut="resetRating();">
    <?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){ 
        if($i<$star)
            { 
                $classz="selected"; 
            } 
            else { 
                $classz=""; 
            }
        ?>
  <li name="star" value="one" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);" class="<?=$classz?>">&#x2605;</li>

    <?php

    } 

    ?>
```